err: bad proposal response 500: cannot create ledger from genesis block: LedgerID already exists
There was a problem with the test network of the fabric.
Commands：
./network.sh createChannel

question
Channel 'mychannel' created
Joining org1 peer to the channel...
Using organization 1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
2024-07-22 21:23:52.879 CST 0001 INFO [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: cannot create ledger from genesis block: LedgerID already exists)
After 5 attempts, peer0.org1 has failed to join channel 'mychannel'

Channel 'mychannel' created
Joining org1 peer to the channel...
Joining org2 peer to the channel...

This can sometimes be caused by state (volumes) from previously created peer containers left behind in the Docker environment. You could try clearing out your Docker environment as described in this issue comment before recreating the network:

./network.sh down
docker system prune --volumes

In some environments I have experienced similar errors caused by what seem to be timing issues when the up and createChannel commands are combined in a single invocation of the ./network.sh script. For me, this was solved by running each command separately. However, from your question description, you seem to be doing this already.
